# -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object Return then Get from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

The following code is returning an exception with the following error message and My Application Crashed, in my code all data store in `NSMutableDictionary` and then store in `NSUserDefaults`
After get the data and assign global `NSMutableDictionary` and i will try to update data in `NSMutableDictionary` app crash and showing error

> -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary * cacheUploadDataDic = [[defaults objectForKey:@"SalaryIncomeData"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Can you show the line that's causing the crash? Are you getting the crash while trying to mutate one of the objects _inside_ the dictionary? `mutableCopy` only makes the _dictionary_ mutable; the objects inside would still be immutable.

Comment: As said by @CharlesSrstka This line of code shouldn't crash. Where does your crash happen? And `mutableCopy` make mutable only the "top level", not the sub-objects. It's not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, it crashes with mutable type issue, all the objects you retrieved from user defaults are inmutable, it uses the plist file to serialized the data list to file, check the plist programming guide about the supported types.

You shall regard the user defaults as a simple   plist file storage wrapper.

Use NSMutableDictionary's 'initWithDictionary:' method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer to the question in my comment does not appear to be forthcoming, I'm just going to go out on a limb and make the guess that your `cacheUploadDataDic` dictionary contains some more `NSDictionary` objects inside of it, and that your crash is occurring when you try to mutate one of those dictionaries. This fails because `mutableCopy` performs a *shallow copy;* only the dictionary object itself is copied, and all of the objects *inside* the dictionary, including any additional dictionaries, remain their original immutable selves.

You can fix this by making a *deep copy* of the dictionary instead. There are a few ways to do this, but the simplest is probably to use the `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` function. Unfortunately, we have to do some bridging, since this API is only available at the CoreFoundation level, the reason for which is one of those eternal mysteries.

Anyway, do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SomeKey"];

NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = CFBridgingRelease(
    CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                 (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict,
                                 kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves)
);
```

You will now be able to mutate the contents of `mutableDict` to your heart's content.

Answer (score -2):

Follow your code, there shows no problem.
Then if possible, you can check the class of `cacheUploadDataDic` before update data and after `NSMutableDictionary * cacheUploadDataDic = [[defaults objectForKey:@"SalaryIncomeData"] mutableCopy]`.
If there are one `NSMutableDictionary` and the other is `NSDictionary` then you must change `cacheUploadDataDic` at other line.
if you can't find out where you change the object,you can try KVO.